# Switching from Docker Desktop to Colima - no localhost access

Tags: docker, colima

Trying to switch to colima from Docker Desktop on mac but having issues reaching my containers on localhost.

Removed Docker Desktop and installed colimna/docker w homebrew. Colima starts fine.

I have a command that I use to run Dynamo:

```
docker run --name dynamodb -d -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local"
```

When I was using Docker Desktop I could reach the database on localhost:8000. Now it's only accessible on 127.0.0.1:8000

My `/etc/hosts` correctly maps localhost - this is an issue with the switch. Not finding much online regarding this - any ideas? It seems that docker no longer recognizes `localhost` as an alias for `127.0.0.1` after the switch. Not using Kubernetes or docker compose.

Comment: Related: [localhost vs 127.0.0.1](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1) and [Docker is inaccessible on localhost but works fine on 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346784/docker-is-inaccessible-on-localhost-but-works-fine-on-127-0-0-1).